# In Hibernate why am I getting Found two representations of same collection when no changes made to this class

Tags: hibernate

I am using `Hibernate` version `4.3.11` with `H2 database` version `1.3.172`

So a customer gets this exception (never had before)

```
Found two representations of same collection: com.jthink.songlayer.Song.coverArts
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: com.jthink.songlayer.Song.coverArts
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:170)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:59)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:82)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:172)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.analyseFiles(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:296)
at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.updateItunes(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:175)
at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:185)
at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown S
```

I know this can hapen for a number of reasons, but the weird thing is this is happening when I commit the transaction and during the particular hibernate session I only load a class I never actually make any changes to this particular class

My `Song` class had this link to `coverArts'

```
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<CoverArt> coverArts;
```

> CoverArt class is

```
package com.jthink.songlayer;


import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;

    /**
     * Links between a song and the artwork for that song.
     */
    @Audited
    @Entity
    public class CoverArt
    {
        private String  imageType;
        private String  description;

        @OneToOne
        private CoverImage coverImage;

        public CoverArt()
        {

        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @Version
        private int version;

        public String getImageType()
        {
            return imageType;
        }

        public void setImageType(String imageType)
        {
            this.imageType = imageType;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public CoverImage getCoverImage()
        {
            return coverImage;
        }

        public void setCoverImage(CoverImage coverImage)
        {
            this.coverImage = coverImage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When it occurs while doing merge or update.

Comment: Its due to a save() when committing.

Comment: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
                       CascadeType.MERGE })` try your mapping this way.

Comment: @SumeshTG Could you explain the reasoning please.

Comment: You missing `mapped by`  . create an object of song in coverArts and give the object name as mapped by in oneToMany

Comment: But why do I have to do this ?